# How to limit resources for airflow task or prevent execution of tasks which start spark jobs locally

Tags: python, apache-spark, airflow

We administer Airflow cluster and different teams launch their DAGs on that cluster. These DAGs have to start very heavy spark jobs on many cores with hundreds Tb of RAM. Time-to-time someone launch these jobs in local mode on airflow node and it causes airflow go out of service. Is there any way to prevent launch of these tasks or prevent importing such DAGs? Or may be is there any way to limit resources for airflow tasks?

Comment: how is someone triggering these jobs in local mode on an airflow node?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have you're either using `LocalExecutor` or `CeleryExecutor` with your airflow node set as a Celery worker?

If the latter, you might consider deploying a worker node that is designated for Airflow tasks, and remove your Airflow service node as a Celery worker.

If the former, you could consider making changes on the `spark-submit` or Spark configuration side to prevent users from running jobs in local mode.

Answer (score 0):

What type of dag executor you're using? We are using KubernetesExecutor, and have set cpu/memory resource limits inside podTemplate, something like following

```
resources:
limits:
  cpu: 16
  memory: 64Gi
requests:
  cpu: 16
  memory: 64Gi
```